# ArcMap Northing and Easting Starting Point vs. 'Northeast Corner Section 8' difference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cogo, plss

I have a legal description that states the section starting point and the Northing and Easting Coordinates. Upon typing the Northing and Easting into my COGO table it is about 20 feet off. Which one would be the better choice to start from? I am leaning on the side of the Northeast section corner.

Would it be best for me to start at the exact Northing and Easting or the Northeast corner of section 28? Is there a recommendation to deal with this sort of situation?

[image: Northing and Easting starting point]

[image: Northing and Easting starting point image]

[image: Northeast corner starting point]

[image: Ruler measurement showing difference]

Comment: What's the coordinate system? There could be datum or UOM issues.

Comment: @Mintx The data frame properties and the data layer are both in NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_V_FIPS_0405_Feet.

Comment: This is a common challenge in GIS. How trustworthy is your basemap and data? Are you comfortable being wrong? If this is for any sort of legal work, then you really need to research why these layers aren't lining up.

Comment: Please explain what your pictures are showing? Which is the PLSS corner? I would trust the one closest to the street intersection, which might be tied to the PLSS corner. Is there a physical corner monument you can locate? Also, keep in mind that this region of California has a surprisingly high rate of continental drift which means that you have to make sure that your different layers account for the dates they were created/projected.

Comment: @Llaves pic 1 is my northing and easting given to me by my legal description. pic 2 shows the location in space  of the northing and east with the background of a map layer of LA County Streets (they don't have a LA County Streets Shapefile Layer) provided by the County of Los Angeles Enterprise Geographic Information Systems. Pic three shows the starting dot on the northeast corner of section 28. Pic 4 shows the distance difference between both locations.

Comment: @tmo - so if I understand, the bright green lines represent section boundaries. Is that right? While answers to Mintx's questions would be informative, my gut tells me that your property corner is more likely to coincide with the street intersection than to be in some random place, and that this is all explained by differences in when the surveys were taken, since they are in the same CRS, but perhaps in different epochs.

Comment: @Mintx The section layer data I have pulled from the BLM website. This is a legal description for a garbage disposal district. I spoke with a Board of Equalization employee and they stated they do not do engineering when checking the data so I am leaning towards going with the section layer point of beginning because that is what other GISer's would use when confirming the COGO metes and bounds. The pdf map layer (from LA County Enterprise GIS) was used to confirm a street intersection in Palmdale (at that point I had not discovered a street layer which housed all street names in LA County).

Comment: @Llaves Thank you for the response I responded to Mintx's question. I am leaning towards using the section lines because according to mappers at the LA Board of Equalization that is what they use when confirming metes and bounds and are not concerned with the precise engineering. You are probably correct in your analysis. I want it to be accurate however as the engineer mentions both starting points in the legal description I think I will default to the PLSS starting points as that is what I would assume other GIS users would use. Alas, I was hoping I could have both POB's match.